# Discord.NET 0.9.4 Audio does play with NAudio

Tags: c#, api, naudio, discord

I folllowed [this](http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/en/legacy/features/voice.html#the-iaudioclient) documentation about the Discord.NET 0.9.4 API. Now i have this function called SendAudio, but i don't know how to call it correctly. I currently have this test code:

```
musicgroup.CreateCommand("play").Do((e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hey, that's pretty good!");
    SendAudio(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\test.mp3");
});
```

It displays the "Hey, that's pretty good!" in the command line and the bot does show up in the Voice Chat, but i can't hear any sound. The bot has all permissions to talk. When i type !voice (the command to make the bot join Voice-Chat) I get this output in console:

```
[BOT] Unknown Opcode: 8
[BOT] Connected
```

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` already has a trailing slash on it so you don't need to add another, but that's not the problem here.